# Possible to use screen via ssh without -t?

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnu-screen, tty

I am in a bit of a tricky situation where I need to connect to a server via SSH through a Jenkins plugin. There is no option to pass in the `-t` flag and get myself a `pseudo-tty` session so I can use `screen`.

Is there anyway to get around this once already connected besides establishing a nested SSH session?

Comment: Why the `screen`
 on top of ssh?

Comment: Great question - I need to capture a pre-existing screen spawned in a windows node so I can launch a GUI application.

Comment: does `screen -m` helps?

Comment: Nice, that could be what I'm looking for. Hopefully this will run in a non-tty terminal. I'll test this out, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use screen to display something, you will need a terminal.

If you only want to start a new session, but not display it, invoke `screen -m -d`. The session starts out detached.

If you only want to interact with an existing session, use the `-X` option to send a command to that session. This doesn't attach to the session and doesn't require a terminal. Note that if a screen session was started in detached mode, its initial window is not active, so you'll probably need to select the window with `-p` before doing anything, e.g.

```
screen -d -m long-running-command
screen -p 1 -X stuff 'yes^M'
```

Whatever you do you'll probably want to use a reproducible session name and always pass the `-S` option so you know which session you're talking to.